# iText/iTextSharp 5.5.0 has error with pdf burst

Tags: pdf, itext

Below code works fine on iTextSharp 5.2.1

```
var file= new FileInfo(args[0]);
string name = file.Name.Substring(0,file.Name.LastIndexOf("."));                
// we create a reader for a certain document
var reader = new PdfReader(args[0]);
// we retrieve the total number of pages
int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");
Document document;
string filename;
PdfCopy copy;

for (int pageNumber = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) 
{
    filename = pageNumber.ToString();
    filename = "_" + filename + ".pdf";
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber ));
    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
    copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(name + filename,FileMode.Create));
    // step 3: we open the document
    document.Open();
    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber));
    // step 5: we close the document
    document.Close();
}
```

But it throws below error on iTextSharp 5.5.0,

> The page 1 was requested but the document has only 0 pages.

it seems like that the last line actually tampered the reader instance. Could someone help me figure it out? Now I walkaround this by recreating a PdfReader instance for each page, but that is slow for large PDF file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally nailed it. It's a change of iText in recent version that caused this issue, specifically, the issue lies in the `WriteAllPages` of the `PdfReaderInstance.cs` file. In it, the line

```
file.Close();
```

is the culprit. The reason is that `Document.Close` method will call `PdfCopy.Close` method which will in turn call `PdfReaderInstance.WriteAllPages` method and then all hells break loose.

On the surface, it seems a good practice to close the file, but really, it's none of your business, damn you, `PdfReaderInstance`.

Hope this info helps others.

Comment: @chrispepper1989, it's been a while since I wrote the answer, but from the root cause analysis, the walk around is obvious, don't call `document.Close();` at the end

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp page numbers are one-based, not zero. These two lines are accounting for this correctly:

```
pagenumber = i + 1;

document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagenumber));
```

However this line is still going back to the zero-based index of your loop:

```
copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
```

You could just change that to:

```
copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));
```

Of you could just make your entire loop one-based and not think about having to add one every once in a while

```
for (int pagenumber = 1; pagenumber <= n; pagenumber++) 
{
    filename = pagenumber.ToString();
    while (filename.Length< digits) filename = "0" + filename;
    filename = "_" + filename + ".pdf";
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagenumber));
    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
    copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(name+filename,FileMode.Create));
    // step 3: we open the document
    document.Open();
    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));
    // step 5: we close the document
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that code with such a bug is claimed to have worked for TextSharp 5.2.1...

Comment: Hi, this piece of code is not mine. My code is actually indeed using one-based index, but it's more complex so I searched a bit for the code example. So the issue is not indexing, but the behavior change of iText.

Comment: I updated the example code to make it less confusing. But please see the error that I posted and the walkaround I am using right now.

Comment: All 5.2.x versions of iText have been removed from the official repositories because they contained a very serious bug: http://itextpdf.com/changelog/52

Comment: The thing is that I am using iTextSharp 5.5.0.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, because that I have to recreate the reader in the body of the for loop, this is causing OutOfMemory issue with large files

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I think what I described in my answer is in fact a bug, please look into it.

Comment: Can you please share a PDF document you have problems with? It seems that bug depends on the input file. We cannot reproduce it locally with random PDF documents.